# Session state value doesn't appear in my label

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

I'm working on a hit counter for my webpage in c# asp.net. I'm trying to use session state to display the string value of the hit counter from one web form and place it in another web form. It works but only after I navigate the links back and forth to test the increment, otherwise the first time I load the page the hit counter count doesn't display on the label. Any clue how i could fix this, I thought about using a cookie. But even if a first time visitor came to my page, my hit counter still wouldn't display correctly. I'm pretty desperate to solve this.

Here is the session state code I was trying with.

Form that is trying to display the label

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

  namespace VideoWebsite
  {
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
                string field1 = (string)(Session["field1"]);
                Label1.Text = field1;
        }

       }

    }
```

Form where I'm trying to get the session state value from

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConnection conn;
       SqlCommand cmd;

       using (conn)
        {
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();
            //send the query and store the results in a sqldatareader
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                //set the text of our label to the current # of hits
                lblHits.Text = "Default Page Hits - " +  
               rdr["Hits"].ToString();
            }

            Session["field1"] = rdr["Hits"].ToString(); 

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not display when first accessed because that session variable does not exist yet. You are only creating it in the second web form.

You should move that code that reads the information from the database to the session created event handler from global.asax.

Sorry I cannot post code, I'm typing from the Android app.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

       {

         // Your Hits read code goes here

       }
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how session states work,  any way I can work around this, so it will display even if I'm a first time visitor to the webpage.

Comment: The session state gets created on the first access of the application, indeed. But that session variable, you are only creating it when accessing the second web form. Until then it does not exist and will return null.

Comment: I see. The problem though is the value I need is in my other form, the entire point of session state was to move the value to another form, but I want the hit count to display for first time visitors as well. I thought about solving this with a cookie. But first time visitors or people who delete their cookies will still have this problem. Any simple idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Do you mean the Query connection that is getting the information from the database? You think I should move that to Application_Start event? or Session_start?

Comment: Depends on what that Hits value is intended for. If it's value has meaning only for the current user, user the session created event. If it's meaning is global, use the application start event. But in this case, store the value in the Application object, rather than the Session object.

Comment: The hit value will be used to display views on a video pages, Sort of like youtube. I'm going to be keeping track of a lot of videos. I was trying to figure out smarter way to do this. Since there going to be a lot of videos.

Comment: Then you shouldn't cache it at all, but rather read it from the database together with all the other video related information. That's how I'd do it. You actually have to track each video's hit count so it makes sense this way.

Comment: I tried to place my query connection in the session_start event handler in my global.asax.cs and it's giving me a error Use of unassigned local variable 'conn'. and use of unassigned local variable 'cmd'.

Comment: I'm starting to think that's the way to go. But i wanted to just find a way to not have write so much code to do something simple, or at least seem simple.

Comment: That's because your code is not assigning instances to conn and cmd. Have a closer look at your code.

Comment: It would be wrong not to do it like this. Data should stay in the data store. Only caching would be ok, but you cache things that don't change as much. A hit counter does change a lot and makes your cache expired very fast.

Comment: Yea I fixed the code and it works. I'm going to follow your advice Mihai and just pull the values straight from the database, you are right, eventually I plan to do other stuff with the database like place meta-tags and descriptions, and I'm going to need a way to keep track of all that anyways. Thanks for the help and advice.